# CakePHP 2.1 CakeEmail to send an email

Tags: email, sendmail, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I wanna send an email to user. 
So the code I used is below.

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
public function sendMail($to, $subject, $data) {

    // Set the Params
    $email = new CakeEmail('default');
    $email->from(array('admin@admin.com' => 'Admin'));
    $email->emailFormat('text');
    $email->to($to);
    $email->subject($subject);

    // Send Email
    if($email->send($data)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function returns true but I am not getting an email.Please suggest me where i am going wrong. Advance Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Probably a server or mail delivery issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a myriad of reasons. Check the configuration settings in **app/Config/email.php**. You’ll need an SMTP server to relay your email.